# Debian not placing files to correct folder

Tags: debian

I need help in order to know what I'm doing wrong. I want to create a .deb for installing new logos in Zeppelin. My .deb has DEBIAN with control inside and the folders: Library>Zeppelin>"Mynewlogos". Ok, I create the .deb but when I install it with iFile, it installs corretly but places the files in the root directory, not inside Library>Zeppelin taht is the correct one.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of the the package mechanism. It assumes that all files in the `data.tar.gz` archive have a *full* path name starting in the root directory. In order to create a correct archive you will simply have to mimic the target file system. Suppose that your sub directory `Library/Zeppelin` has this full path:

```
/path/to/the/subdirectory/Library/Zeppelin
```

Create the fake directory structure

```
/tmp/fakefs/PACKAGENAME/path/to/the/subdirectory/Library/Zeppelin
```

and populate the required files there. Of course, this will typically have to include the sub directory

```
/tmp/fakefs/PACKAGENAME/DEBIAN
```

containing the Debian control files.

Then, `cd` into `/tmp/fakefs` and call the `dpkg-deb` command from there like this:

```
dpkg-deb -b PACKAGENAME
```

This will create a Debian file `PACKAGENAME.deb` with the correct file paths in it.